# Using two buttons on a form to pass button value to AJAX/PHP scripts

Tags: php, ajax, forms, button

I have a form which links to a PHP script using an AJAX script.  Up to now I have had a single submit button to process the form which passes values to the PHP script to generate the sending of an email.  Now I would like to have two options on the form, either to send the email or to view the email first before sending it.  I am thinking that having two buttons with the same class that triggers the AJAX/PHP script would be the way to go.  Each button could have a different value and depending on this value, the scripts could behave in a different way.

I am not sure if using two buttons is the best way of handling this.  If it is though, I am not sure how to handle the values in the buttons.  Does only the value of the button that is clicked get passed?

The rest of the values in my form are processed in the following way (as there are multiple forms on the page):

```
var form_data = {
    name: $jform.find("[id^=name]").val(),
    date: $jform.find("[id^=date]").val(),
    time: $jform.find("[id^=time]").val(),
};
```

How do I include the value of the button though?  There would be two buttons that would look something like this:

```
echo "<button type='submit' class='submit_s' value='view'>View</button>";
echo "<button type='submit' class='submit_s' value='email'>Email</button>";
```

Presumably I can't have two buttons with the same id, and as I mentioned before I am not sure if both button values are passed when I click on one.

I would like to be able to do something like this in the AJAX script:

```
if (button == 'email') {
    $jform.fadeOut(800);
}
```

What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: Just give them different IDs then. There's no reason you can't.

Comment: You could write a JS function that takes the value of the submit button `onclick` and store it in a hidden field ID's "button".

Comment: @NicholasPickering Thanks, could you help with the JS function for this?

Comment: Done. My jQuery is a little weak so let me know if it doesn't work right.

Answer (score 0):

Your input buttons must have different name.

```
echo "<button type='submit' name="name1" class='submit_s' value='view'>View</button>";
echo "<button type='submit' name="name2" class='submit_s' value='email'>Email</button>";
```

after this, you can do this in form

```
$jform.find("input[name=name1]").click(function() { 
     $jform.submit();
})
```

or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, would it not be better to store the value of the submit button in a hidden field ID as suggested by Nicholas Pickering above?  That way I could use the same AJAX script for both purposes, with just the submit button value differing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JS function to set the value of a common field to keep track of which button was pressed.

Add code to pick up new field which will be set by our JS function:

```
var form_data = {
    name: $jform.find("[id^=name]").val(),
    date: $jform.find("[id^=date]").val(),
    time: $jform.find("[id^=time]").val(),
    button: $jform.find("[id^=button]").val(),
};
```

Our new JS function to set the hidden field's value:

```
function setHiddenButtonValue(buttonValue)
{
    $("#button").value = buttonValue;
    return true;
}
```

Add the onclick events to our buttons so that when clicked they update the hidden field. Also draw the new hidden field:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='button' value='' />";
echo "<button type='submit' class='submit_s' value='view' onclick='return setHiddenButtonValue(this.value);'>View</button>";
echo "<button type='submit' class='submit_s' value='email' onclick='return setHiddenButtonValue(this.value);'>Email</button>";
```

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to be along the right lines, only the id of the hidden button inputs isn't `#button` so `$("#button").value = buttonValue;` wouldn't work, would it?  They are in the form button1, button2, button3, etc.

Comment: $.(#button) is the id of the hidden form field thats been added, not each of the buttons. Each button needs to get their onclick event set to the new function so they can set the field that is being used to check which button was pressed.

Comment: Yes, it's the hidden form fields that have the ids button1, button2, button3, etc.  There are multiple forms on the page, hence the need for ids in this form.

Comment: I thought I might be able to use `$j("[id^=button]").value = buttonValue;`, but to no avail...